# Cannot find blueman icon in system tray

Tags: bluetooth, 14.04

After I upgrade to 14.04 LTS, I can't find blueman icon in my system tray. The blueman-applet is up well and I can use blueman to manage my devices. Any idea on this?

Comment: I have the same problem.